# I want to solve these differential equations and plot X(0,z/G)

Tags: differential-equations

```
μ = 1.82*10^-5; 
D1 = 7.2*10^-5; 
ρ = 0.04; 
u0 = 4; 
R = 0.15; 
G = 28.26; 

NDSolve[{D[u[r, z], {z, 1}] == -(v[r, z]/r) - D[v[r, z], {r, 1}], u[r, z] D[u[r, z], {z, 1}] + v[r, z] D[u[r, z], {r, 1}] == μ/(ρ r) D[u[r, z], {r, 1}] + μ/ρ D[u[r, z], {r, 2}], u[r, z] D[x[r, z], {z, 1}] + v[r, z] D[x[r, z], {r, 1}] == D1/ r D[x[r, z], {r, 1}] + D1 D[x[r, z], {r, 2}], v[0, 0] == 0, u[0, 0] == 8, x[0, 1.13] == 0.01, v[0, z] == 0, u[R, 0] == 0}, {u, v, x}, {r, 0, R}, {z, 0, 0.2}]
```

Comment: And what's the actual problem you have? Elaborate more please.

Comment: This code that I wrote does not work. And I don't know Plot's command either

Comment: Are these typos `v[0, 0] == 0, u[0, 0] == 8, x[0, 1.13] == 0.01`?